# Given a TFS changeset, how can I find what work item(s) it is linked to?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, changeset, tfs-power-tools, tf-cli

It's easy to see what changesets are linked to a given work item. But is it possible, given a changeset, to find out what work item(s) it is linked to?

Comment: are you looking for API way of doing ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the changeset number then in TFS explorer in VS press `CRTL + G` and provide the changeset number and click OK. That will bring the change set in team explorer.

Then you can click on a folder/file and select `view history` which will show you the work items related to it. See [view changesets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181408.aspx#view) for more information.

Also, check out this MSDN blog post [Listing the work items associated with changesets for a path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/02/01/listing-the-work-items-associated-with-changesets-for-a-path.aspx)

Comment: Huh? I am in VS and nowhere does CTRL+G do anything. Where is "TFS Explorer in VS"?

Comment: @smartyollie What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @smartyollie In Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 you can achieve what @Rahul said by pressing `CRTL + G` anywhere in the **Source Control Explorer*

Comment: I think "TFS explorer" should have read "Source Control Explorer". This works in Source Control Explorer in TFS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

(From my Visual Studio 2017)

In "Team Explorer" click on "Source Control Explorer":

[image]

Click on this icon:

[image]

Put the Changeset number or search it:

[image]

Click on "Details..." (or double-click on the changeset):

[image]